# How to extract first segment out of URI using Uri class

Tags: c#

I am using Uri class for application development and needs the first segment of user-entered uri that either it contains http:// or http:// or ftp:// etc.
If not so,i have to hardcode to add to it.

I have already searched for it using googling and stackoverflowing but they didn't showed the precise requirement for me.

```
string path,downloadURL;
path =  this.savePath.Text;
downloadURL =  this.downloadURL.Text;

// i have done this but it didn't check if already existing .
downloadURL = "http://" + downloadURL;

Uri tmp = new Uri(downloadURL);
//extracts the last element
string EndPathFileName = tmp.Segments.Last();

// something like this but it returns only  '/'.
//string StartPathFileName = tmp.Segments.First();

//Console.WriteLine(StartPathFileName);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few options depending on what behavior you want...

You could just check if it contains `://` which might be enough for what you want:

```
if(!downloadURL.Contains("://"))
    downloadURL = "http://" + downloadURL;
```

Note that this would allow things such as `"rubbish://www.example.com"`

---

If you wanted to be a bit more cautious, you could check if the string starts with one of your predetermined values. For example:

```
if(!downloadURL.StartsWith("http://") && !downloadURL.StartsWith("https://") && !downloadURL.StartsWith("ftp://"))
    downloadURL = "http://" + downloadURL;
```

Though this would mean that `"rubbish://www.example.com"` would become `"http://rubbish://www.example.com"`.

You could go for a mix of both options, but keep in mind it can become very difficult to cope with all kinds of user input.

---

One final suggestion, which is even more robust, might be as follows:

```
string[] approvedSchemes = new string[] { "http", "https", "ftp" };
string userScheme = "";

if(downloadURL.Contains("://"))
{
    // Get the first scheme defined, we will use this if it is in the approved list.
    userScheme = downloadURL.Substring(0, downloadURL.IndexOf("://"));
    // To cater for multiple :// remove all of them
    downloadURL = downloadURL.Substring(downloadURL.LastIndexOf("://") + 3);
}

// Check if the user defined scheme is in the approved list, if not then set to http.
if(Array.IndexOf(approvedSchemes, userScheme.ToLowerInvariant()) > -1)
    downloadURL = userScheme + "://" + downloadURL;
else
    downloadURL = "http://" + downloadURL;
```

[Here is a working example](http://ideone.com/PkglrC)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Uri.Scheme Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");
    Console.WriteLine(baseUri.Scheme); //http

    Uri anotherUri = new Uri("https://www.contoso.com/");
    Console.WriteLine(anotherUri.Scheme); //https
```